# Qt filter out mouse presses

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, eventfilter

I am writing a software for an embedded linux device running qt4.8 with a touch screen.

Right now I am having issues with the touch screen being too sensitive to touch and I would get 2 touches on the screen at once.

What I want to do is filter out any touches after the first after a period of time.

What I have so far is I have installed the eventfilter and listening for mouse events:

```css
qApp->installEventFilter(this);

...

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  switch(event->type()){
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:{
      if(timer.isActive()) return true;
      timer.start();
    }
  }
```

The problem I am having is that when going between pages/menu's in my application the GUI will lag and block the system for longer than my timer. So when the page finally loads, by this time my timer is finished and the 2nd unwanted mouse press is processed...

Is there a better way to do this? Emiting a signal to trigger the time AFTER the new page/menu is loaded?; Threading out the eventfilter to handle mouse presses in a different thread?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that you're applying a time filter based on the time at which the event is *removed* from the queue rather than the time at which the event actually occurred.  You could take a look at [`QAbstractEventDispatcher`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstracteventdispatcher.html) which (I think) allows you to filter events at source.  Or, if the relevant XEvent types on your system have a `time` field you could use [`QWidget::x11Event`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#x11Event) or [`QApplication::x11EventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#x11EventFilter).

Comment: thank you for your help, but I ended up avoiding the problem by calling processEvents after I create the page/menu, and before I show it.